# SQL LIMIT by distinct column value without subqueries

Tags: sql, postgresql

user

| id | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | anna | 6 |
| 2 | john | 10 |
| 3 | lord | 50 |

cats

| id | name | userID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | miez | 1 |
| 2 | caty | 1 |
| 3 | random | 2 |
| 4 | idk | 3 |

When using

```
SELECT U.id, C.name FROM user U
INNER JOIN cats C ON U.id = C.id
LIMIT 2
```

I get as a

result

| UserID | CatName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | miez |
| 1 | caty |

What I want is to limit my rows by the distinct values of UserID, like this

```
SELECT U.id, C.name FROM user U
INNER JOIN cats C ON U.id = C.id
LIMIT 2 <distinct U.id rows>
```

| UserID | CatName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | miez |
| 1 | caty |
| 2 | random |

People suggested using limit in subqueries and check if UserID is in the return
like

```
... WHERE UserID IN (SELECT id FROM User LIMIT 2)
```

but this only works well for small tables and is not an elegant solution for good performance.
My idea was using DENSE_RANK(), like:

```
SELECT U.id, C.name FROM user U
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY U.id) as rows,
INNER JOIN cats C ON U.id = C.id
WHERE rows < 50
```

but it is not working either.

Comment: LIMIT-ing without ORDER-ing makes little sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a column alias on the same level where you define it. You will have to wrap the query in a derived table. However if you want a specific number of row *per user* you need to use `partition by`, not `order by`

```
select id, name
from (
  SELECT u.id, 
         c.name, 
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY U.id ORDER BY c.name) as rnk
  FROM user U
    JOIN cats C ON U.id = C.userid
) t
WHERE t.rnk <= 2
```

Comment: thx for your help. but that would be a solution for smaller tables. you use a subquery for user but don´t limit the results. that´s why I mentioned "without subqueries" because in realitiy I have pretty large tables and can not just query through user with 100000 entries

Comment: The derived table is only syntactic sugar to allow a reference to the column alias in the WHERE clause. It has no impact on the performance of evaluating the `dense_rank()`. 100000  rows isn't considered "pretty large" these days. In fact I consider that a small table.